# Why is the result of "D[y == Log[x*y], x]" "0 == 1/x"?

Tags: differential-equations

In Mathematica 13.3.1, the `D[y == Log[x*y], x]` gives result `0 == 1/x`. It is very weird. At [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/), its result is `y'(x) = y/(x (y - 1))`, which I think should be correct. Why does Mathematica gives that result?

Comment: I think this is wrong syntax. "D" takes an expression not an equation. "D" then takes the derivative of both sides. This gives 0 for the LHS and 1/x for the RHS.

Comment: May you explain why the LHS is 0 and the RHS is 1/x? @DanielHuber

Comment: @DanielHuber `D[]`is able to find derivatives of implicit expressions including equations, see documantation.

Comment: Alternatively, use `Dt`.

Comment: LHS is 0 because D[y,x] is 0. y is considered not to depend on x. The RHS is 1/2 because of  D[Log[x*y], x] == 1/x, again y is considered not to depend on x.

Comment: @xzczd `Dt[y == Log[x*y], x]` doesn't work.

Comment: @DanielHuber I think `D[Log[x*y], x]` should be `y/x` not `1/x` if y is considered not to depend on x.

Comment: Are you sure?: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayoQ5.png

Comment: " I think D[Log[x*y], x] should be y/x not 1/x"…同学你该复习链式法则了。

Comment: @xzczd 你是对的。结果应该是`1/x`. 而且，`Dt`的用法更简单明了。谢谢你。

Comment: Sorry my mistake, you are right.

Comment: @DanielHuber No, you are right. It should be `1/x`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mathematica doesn't know, that you assume `y=y[x]` !

Try

```
D[y[x] == Log[x*y[x]], x]
(*Derivative[1][y][x] == (y[x] + x Derivative[1][y][x])/(x y[x])*)

Solve[%, y'[x]][[1, 1]] /. Rule -> Equal
(*Derivative[1][y][x] == y[x]/(x (-1 + y[x]))*)
```